# Free Download Manager Automatically opens chrome on start

Tags: google-chrome, download-manager

I've downloaded FDM Portable and when I run it, it automatically starts Google Chrome and I don't know why.

My default browser is Firefox.

How do I stop it from launching Chrome?

Comment: It starts Chrome because thats your default browser.  It starts your browser because it was programmed to do that.

Comment: Nope. Firefox is my default browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are experiencing the same problem as me, you can simply **uninstall chrome and reinstall it**.

It is the easiest way to get around this problem (I think).